# How to rotate only the content inside the div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider a `<div>` which have several other elements inside it. The elements flows from top to bottom. I want the content of the div to flow at a different angle(90, 180, 270) but I don't want to rotate the div itself

```css
#color{
  background:blue;
  padding:10px; 
}
#test{
  width:100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="color"></div>
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Price</div>
</div>
```

I want to rotate the above div content at angle of `90` so that it looks like the below one

```css
#color{
  background:blue;
  padding:10px; 
}
#test{
  width:50px;
  height:100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 40% 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="color"></div>
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Price</div>
</div>
```

But as you can see the in above snippet the div is little bit changed from its position. I want the it to   be at the same position after being rotated.

Is there any other good way of rotating elements without using rotate?

Comment: either consider transform-origin combined with translate (duplicate 1) or writing-mode (duplicate 2)

Comment: please share final result what you want at the end, like before and after image

Comment: @TemaniAfif Any of them doesn't work for me both have problems. The first one rotates the whole object I only want to rotate the content. Can you please show the exact solution. More specifically see this [image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cityam.com%2Ftake-look-monopoly-board-thats-been-re-designed-2018-london%2F&psig=AOvVaw3CFFPQ7x2bJem_mfPviKSB&ust=1591854975085000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLiWyobI9ukCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) and tell how to make second. third and fourth row of monopoly board.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62297465/how-to-make-a-monopoly-board-using-css-grid I explained the complete problem here

Comment: adding `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` to your #test div fixes your issue